# Can the same dimension table be related to multiple fact tables?

Tags: olap

I am new to OLAP,if I have two fact tables can they share the same dimension table?

A good example would be if I have tables fact1 and fact2, can they both have a foreign key into a *single* Date dimension (dimDate) table?  Or, do I need/should create separate dimDate dimension tables for each separate fact?

To me, and based on my research, I don't see any downfall of sharing a dim table, but wanted to check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can, and should.

That's the whole point of conformed dimensions, keeping the attributes in a single place, so as to avoid multiple versions of truth coming from different fact tables.

So a single date dimension, with all the necessary attributes for each fact table, which is then linked from each fact table that needs it.

Same for a customer dimension. If you have a sales fact table that needs customer info such as billing address and a marketing fact table that holds info about campaigns each customer can benefit from, you would combine all those attributes in a single table. Some customers may not be referenced in the marketing fact table, others may not exist in the fact table, but all would exist in the single customer dimension, which is your single source of truth about who your customers are.

Comment: Thanks nsousa, that's what I suspected, but always helps to check if I'm setting myself up for unintended problems down the line.